# Взлом БД на выделенном сервере

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте

Насколько правдивая информация о том, что если поставить БД на выделенный сервер и подключаться к ней удаленно (не через localhost) то повышаются риски взлома БД?
Если такие риски существуют, ток как их уменьшить и предотвратить ?
СУБД: mysql.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз сервер mysqld слушает внешний интерфейс, всякий кулхацкер, вооружённый порт-сканером, его может обнаружить. Далее он может зарядить брутфорс подбор паролей от рута, бомбардируя его попытками залогиниться. Если пароль от рута простой - его рано или поздно подберут.

Т.е. формально ответ **«да»**: лишний открытый порт, сервис принимающий соединения извне — риск взлома повышается.

Как предотвратить — читайте про безопасность MySQL и ОС вашего выделенного сервера. Надо отсечь все возможности, кроме предусмотренных: напр. если вы ожидаете подключения к MySQL только с определённого сервера, чей IP известен, надо запретить подключения со всех остальных. Ну и пароль у MySQL root'а поменяйте.

Answer (score 2):

Для защиты удаленного подключения к БД можно использовать ssh-туннелирование или vpn, но при этом будет теряется скорость коннекта к базе из-за шифрования, плюс потери на самом канале. если база более или менее загружена, то это может стать проблемой.